# Setting background color to text in ConTeXt (Mark IV)

Tags: color, backgrounds, context-mkiv

I need to highlight some text in ConTeXt to get something like this:

[image: highlighted text]

Concerning background colors, all I've found in the manual is [some example with `\framed` command](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Color#Cloning_existing_colors), which is inappropriate to me because it breaks the layout.

Comment: Also see: https://randomdeterminism.wordpress.com/2010/10/31/can-i-borrow-your-highlighter-please/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the command
[\defineunderbar](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/underbar). See example:

```
\setuplayout
  [width=9.4cm]

\definebar
  [foobar]
  [color=yellow,
   rulethickness=1.2em,
   offset=1.2,
   continue=yes,
   order=background]

\starttext
There must be \foobar{a way to set the background color when I need to
highlight multiple lines of text. And then return to normal mode} without
affecting the layout.
\stoptext
```

[image: screenshot]